# Error: There are multiple entries in the deeplink config with the name of Page

Tags: node.js, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I recently moved some files from one project to another and everything was working fine before. Now I am getting this error when I try `ionic serve`.

[image]

It states error `AddChemicalPage`, but that is the first page in the pages directory. It has to be `ionic-app-script`, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Help is Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I overlooked the Cordova CLI : not installed and I'm assuming that was causing the issues. `npm install -g cordova` and everything workd fine after that.